# How can I close the browser after a mocha test?

Tags: mocha.js, webdriver-io, wdio-v5

I am new to WebdriverIO and Mocha and I wrote 2 tests in order to check our web app.

I want to close the browser and sign-in again, after I run the first test.
When I used `browser.close()`, I got an error the `browser.close()` is not a function and basically the second test runs right after the first test with the browser being open.

Is there a way to close to browser after a test in Mocha?

```
describe('Verify that a signed-in user can get to the page', () => {
  it('Title assertion ', () => {
    const viUrl = 'https://buyermanage.com/bmgt/lock?useMock=pre.json';
    signInPage.signIn('rich221', 'password', viUrl);
    assert.equal(preApp.getTitle(), 'Pre-App', 'Title Mismatch');
  });
});

describe("Verify that a not signed-in user can't get to the page and is redirected to login page", () => {
  it('Title assertion ', () => {
    const viUrl = 'https://buyermanage.com/bmgt/lock?useMock=pre.json';
    assert.equal(preApp.getTitle(), 'Pre-App', 'Title Mismatch');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`browser.reloadSession()`](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/reloadSession.html):

```
after(() => {
    // Start a new session for every 'locale' (wipe browser cache):
    browser.reloadSession();
});
```

In your particular example, you'd need to use it in the `afterEach()` hook, and wrap the `describes`, respectively the `it` statements (*depending on your test-suite requirements*) inside a parent `describe` block:

```
describe('The world is your oister', () => {

  describe('Verify that a signed-in user can get to the page', () => {
    it('Title assertion ', () => {
      // bla bla bla
    });
  });

  describe("Verify that a not signed-in user can't get to the page and is redirected to login page", () => {
    it('Title assertion ', () => {
      // bla bla bla
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    browser.reloadSession();
  });
});
```